# Unused References in c# application

Tags: c#

I develop WinForms applications.
How can I understand which references that I have added to my application are in use, and which ones are unused?

**If I don't remove unused references, will they degrade my application performance?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unused references will not cause any performance loss when you run your application. Your references are used at compile time to look up unknown symbols.

It is just extra information given to your compiler; telling it where to look for symbols. When the compilation is over, it is no longer needed.

Comment: Updated my answer, as a side note, ReSharper can detect unused references.

Answer (score 1):

One way to see if reference is used by your code (without external tools) is to simply remove that reference and compile.

Used in the code? You'll get nice error message, just add it back.

Not used? Compile succeed and you can leave it removed.

If the reference is to your own project in the same Solution and there are few classes only, you can right click each class in Visual Studio and choose *Find All References* - if something is referencing that class you'll see it.

Comment: No problem @Wish by the way you don't have to bold your comments - they're visible enough with the ordinary text font.

Comment: @Joel oh I gave up on this long ago... thumbs up for not giving up. :)

Comment: Usually true but I think that you can potentially have "hidden" references if you're using reflection and the like.

Answer (score 0):

You can use extensions for VS. You can find them in VS Gallery. You can try this one:
[Reference Assistant](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/fc504cc6-5808-4da8-ae86-8d3f9ed81606)